# Software that can take a whole folder of videos and rip the audio into mp3 format with just one click?

Tags: software-rec, audio, mp3, ripping, video-conversion

I know there's literally thousands of programs that let you rip mp3 audio from videos that you've downloaded, but I want one that will let me give it a list of 50+ files to convert, let me walk away for an hour, and then come back to have all of them finished and the mp3 files waiting for me. So far the programs I looked at require you to enter the location of each video individually, and I feel incredible stupid when I have to do that 50 time over when all the files are just sitting in one folder. It just feels *really* wrong having to do all that for such a simple task.

Does anyone know of software that will let me do this? I don't care if its GUI or command-line. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a couple batch files that will take all files in the current folder with a certain extension and then feed them one at a time to something like [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to extract the audio.

Since you didn't specify which OS you're using, this is done with Windows in mind:

Batch file 1 (the one you'll run in the folder containing the videos you want to extract from, assuming AVI for the example):

```
for %%i IN (*.avi) DO (ripsound.bat "%%i")
```

Save it as `go.bat` or something.

Create the 2nd batch file:

```
ffmpeg -i %1 -vn -acodec mp3 %1.mp3
```

Save it as the first batch references ("ripsound.bat" in this example).

When run, the first batch file will take each .AVI file in the current folder and run the 2nd batch file against it, which will use ffmpeg to convert the video to an MP3 audio file of the same name.

You may have to make some changes to the ffmpeg launching batch (2nd one) to match your needs/wants (different codecs, add an output file path, etc.).

If this doesn't "just work" as-is, at least it will hopefully be a good starting point. :)

Comment: Why can't that be accomplished in one batch file: `for %%i in (*.avi) do (ffmpeg -i %%i -vn -acodec mp3 %%i.mp3`?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that seems complicated. And FFMPEG is slooooow, IMHO!

You can use the free version of Goldwave, version 4 (probably 4.26 something) 
Its got a BATCH function (under tools/options on the main menu? 
[1] just drag and drop your bunch of files into it,
[2] save it as MP3.

http://www.goldwave.com/release426.php

For just ONE file at a time: it's just opening the avi, and [Save As...] MP3. By default, it's set at 128kbps, but you can change that.

I guess if you're looking to spend time and LEARN a lot of technical stuff, you should go the FFMPEG way.

Answer (score 1):

I developed a tool aimed for Linux and for converting a large amount of files. I had like 200GB of flac files that I needed to convert to mp3, and I came up with this extremely complicated solution, but yet working based on [PyDub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub).

It's called [AudioConverter](https://github.com/inlakin/AudioConverter) and you can go over to GitHub to get more details.

I need some beta testers to get better feedback.

#### Basic usage

```
AudioConverter flac --check --path=path/to/music/folder --output_file=logerr.txt
```

This command will first check all the flac files in the `path/to/music/folder` folder and then proceed to the conversion. If any error is encountered, they will be output in the logerr.txt file.

If the user wants to proceed with the conversion, a new folder will be created for storing each of the converted folder (i.e. If we are converting the "Apparat" folder that contains only flac files, a new folder "Apparat - mp3" will be created containing all the mp3 files.)

Comment: Answer posts are intended for definitive solutions.  If you're looking for beta testers, it sounds like maybe this is premature as an answer.

Comment: Yeah but well, it's working on my end, so why not share it ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I've always used WinFF.  It's an FFMpeg front end, available for Windows and Linux.

You do have to tell it you are converting to audio, then mp3.  You can drag a bunch of files to it (.mp4, .flv, etc.), hit Convert, and it will spawn a command line or shell that goes through all of them and converts.  No user intervention necessary.